# How can I handle checkbox value if empty in php when I use serialize() in form?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can I handle checkbox value if empty in php when I use serialize() in form?

mycode ajax like this :

```
function ringkas_sekarang(){
          $("#myModal").modal('show');
          var id=$("#select_uji").val();    
          $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"<?php echo site_url()?>/c_index/hitung_knn",
          data: $("#formku").serialize(),
          success:function(data) {
          $("#myModal").modal('hide');
          $("#sesudah_ringkas").html("<textarea style='text-align:justify;padding:20px;border:none;font-size:12px;width:48%;height:380px;float:right' readonly >"+data+"</textarea>");
          }
        });
}
```

my html code like this:

```
    <form action="#" method="POST" id="formku">
      <li style="font-weight:bold">Pilih Dokumen</li>
        <select style="background:white;pading:5px;width:100%; height:25px;border:1px solid gray;" id= "select_uji" name="id">
          <option>-- Silahkan pilih dokumen --</option>
      <?php
      $i=1;
      foreach ($artikel_uji as $key => $value) {
      ?>
        <option name="id" id= "select_uji" value='<?php echo $value->id?>'> <?php echo 'Dokumen ke -' .$value->id; ?></option>;
      <?php
        }
      ?>
        </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <li style="font-weight:bold"> Judul Artikel:
        <h5 style="font-size:12px;padding:5px;border:1px solid gray;background:white;font-weight:normal" id="title_articel"> <br/><br/></h5>
      </li>
      <li style="font-weight:bold">Ringkas Berdasarkan :</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur[]" value="0">Posisi Kalimat di Paragraf(F1)</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur[]" value="1">Posisi Kalimat di Dokumen(F2)</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur[]" value="2">Data Numerik(F3)</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur[]" value="3">Tanda Petik Dua(F4)</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur[]" value="4">Panjang kalimat(F5)</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="pilih_fitur[]" value="5">Kata kunci(F6)</li>
      <br>
      <li><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ringkas_sekarang()" type="button" style="float: left;border-radius:0px;background-color:#0866C6">RINGKAS SEKARANG</button></li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
    </form>
```

I want to handle if no checkbbox checked and press button submit, there is notification like "you must select fiture.."

Comment: `if ( ! isset($_POST['pilih_fitur']) ) {`

Comment: @RiggsFolly can I applied in my function `ringkas_sekarang()` ?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly do something like this perhaps - serialise the form data and check if the required field is present.

```
function ringkas_sekarang(){
    var formdata=$("#formku").serialize();
    if( formdata.indexOf('pilih_fitur')==-1 ) {
        alert('you must select fiture');
        return false;
    }
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
    var id=$("#select_uji").val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo site_url()?>/c_index/hitung_knn",
        data: formdata,
        success:function(data) {
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
            $("#sesudah_ringkas").html("<textarea style='text-align:justify;padding:20px;border:none;font-size:12px;width:48%;height:380px;float:right' readonly >"+data+"</textarea>");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: perfect solution.. thanks @RamRaider.. it can solved my problem..:)